# How to close client socket in udp

Tags: go

I have a simple UDP server all that I want is if the IP is equal to 1.1.1.1 for example the client socket will close its like a blacklist system

My code

```
func main() {
        arguments := os.Args
        if len(arguments) == 1 {
                fmt.Println("Please provide a port number!")
                return
        }
        PORT := ":" + arguments[1]

        s, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp4", PORT)
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                return
        }

        connection, err := net.ListenUDP("udp4", s)
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                return
        }

        defer connection.Close()
        buffer := make([]byte, 1024)

        for {
                n, addr, err := connection.ReadFromUDP(buffer)
                fmt.Print("-> ", string(buffer[0:n-1]))


                data := []byte(strconv.Itoa(random(1, 1001)))
                fmt.Printf("data: %s\n", string(data))
                _, err = connection.WriteToUDP(data, addr)
                if err != nil {
                        fmt.Println(err)
                        return
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: UDP is stateless, so there's nothing to close when it comes to clients. If you don't want to serve a client, simply don't respond.

Comment: im sorry im kinda bad at this. how can I do this ?

Comment: After `net.ListenUDP()` look at `connection.RemoteAddr().Network()`. You can use `net.SplitHostPort()` to extract the part to compare with `"1.1.1.1"`.

Comment: So basically I need to add `connection.RemoteAddr().Network()` to the for loop and then if I found the same IP  for example `"1.1.1.1"` I do continue ?